# Problem on Android Studio (Kotlin). RecyclerView in Fragment not showing anythig

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment`, but the fragment is not showing anything. I thereby use a database for the app's data.

Can someone help me about this problem, please?
'Cause I'm about to cry :')

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding:FragmentHomeBinding
    private var ceritas:ArrayList<Cerita> = arrayListOf()

    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val q = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
        val url = "https://ubaya.me/native/160821006/get_cerita.php"

        var stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            {
                Log.d("apiresult", it.toString())
                val obj = JSONObject(it)
                if (obj.getString("result")== "OK") {
                    val data = obj.getJSONArray("data")
                    val sType = object : TypeToken<List<Cerita>>() { }.type
                    ceritas = Gson().fromJson(data.toString(), sType) as ArrayList<Cerita>
                    Log.e("apiresult", ceritas.toString())

                    updateList()
                }
            },
            {
                Log.e("apiresult", it.message.toString())
            }
        )
        q.add(stringRequest)
    }

    fun updateList() {
        //binding.recyclerViewHome.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        //binding.recyclerViewHome.adapter = CerbungAdapter(ceritas)
        val lm = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        with(binding.recyclerViewHome) {
            layoutManager = lm
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            adapter = CerbungAdapter(ceritas)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            HomeFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {

                }
            }
    }
}
```

**An Adapter (CerbungAdapter.kt)**

```
class CerbungAdapter(val ceritas:ArrayList<Cerita>):RecyclerView.Adapter<CerbungAdapter.CerbungViewHolder>() {
    class CerbungViewHolder(val binding: CardHomeBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CerbungViewHolder {
        val binding = CardHomeBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return CerbungViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ceritas.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CerbungViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //untuk mengisi informasi yang ada pada cardview playlist
        val url = ceritas[position].url_img
        val builder = Picasso.Builder(holder.itemView.context)
        builder.listener { picasso, uri, exception -> exception.printStackTrace() }
        Picasso.get().load(url).into(holder.binding.imageViewPoster)

        with(holder.binding) {
            txtTitle.text = ceritas[position].title
            txtParagraf.text = ceritas[position].description
            txtNama.text = ceritas[position].user_name

            var tmp = Global.paragrafs.filter {
                data -> data.id == Global.ceritas[position].id
            }

            var totalLikes = tmp.sumBy {
                paragraf -> Global.likes.count { likes -> likes.paragraf_id == paragraf.id }
            }
            var LikesCerita  = Global.likesCerita.filter {
                data -> data.cerita_id == Global.ceritas[position].id
            }
            totalLikes += LikesCerita.count()

            Log.e("id" + position, Global.ceritas[position].id.toString())
            Log.e("size_paragraf_cerita" + position , Global.paragrafs.size.toString())

            txtParagraf.text = tmp.size.toString()
            txtLikes.text = totalLikes.toString()

            btnRead.setOnClickListener {
                Log.e("kirim dari adapter", Global.ceritas[position].id.toString())


                    val intent = Intent(it.context, ReadActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("id", Global.ceritas[position].id)
                    it.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Class (Cerita.kt)**

```
data class Cerita(var id:Int,var title:String, var description:String, var url_img:String, var status:Int, var genre_idgenre: String, var user_name:String, var create_at:String, var last_update:String)
```

**Global class (Global.kt)**

```
object Global {
  // var likes = arrayListOf<Likes>()
   var paragrafs = arrayListOf<Paragraf>()
   var ceritas = arrayListOf<Cerita>()
   var genres = arrayListOf<Genre>()
   var penggunas = arrayListOf<Pengguna>()
   var likes = arrayListOf<Likes>()
   var likesCerita = arrayListOf<LikeCerita>()
   var followCerita = arrayListOf<FollowCerita>()
}
```

**Card for home (card_home.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#939393"
    android:backgroundTint="#939393">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewPoster"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.HeadlineMedium"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewPoster" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNama"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtTitle" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonList"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtNama"
                tools:src="@drawable/baseline_format_list_numbered_24" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButtonList"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtNama" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonLikes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtList"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtNama"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_thumb_up_24" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLikes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButtonLikes"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtNama" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtParagraf"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButtonList" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRead"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="READ"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**XML code for home (fragment_home.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewHome"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:listitem="@layout/card_home"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you creating a new adapter every time you call updateList?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).